# How to solve from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I have this equation: $y(t)=aE^{-bE^{-ct}}$ and I have this list:

```
{{0.11, 0.78}, {0.12, 0.81}, {0.88, 2.37}, {1.17, 2.8}, {1.48, 2.84}, {1.96, 3.2}, {2.98, 3.42}, {3.27, 3.19}, {3.61, 3.23}, {3.75, 3.09}}
```

which is (t, y(t)). Now I want to use that information of y(t) and t to solve in y(t) for a b and c. I think I would have to use each pairs once at a time but is there a command to loop through to entire list and solve using those pairs of values? Thank you.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit`

Comment: You have three variables to solve for but only one condition specified (i.e. $(t,y(t))$ for each point. Do you mean instead to do a fit to the data as noted by @Quantum_Oli?

Comment: Can you tell me more information about the command? I read the documentation for it but I don't quite understand the usage.

Comment: Yes I am trying to find the fitted values for a b and c

Comment: The first example under Basic Examples should show you all you need. Your `data` are your list of values, the instead of `Log[a+b x^a]` put the form of your model, instead of `{a,b}`, your have three fit parameters `{a,b,c}` and you want to fit over `t` not `x` (provided you continue to use `t` in your model).

Comment: This is what I put in: `NonlinearModelFit[tyt, a E^(-bE)^-ct, {a, b, c}, t]` and it's telling me this: `FindFit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.`. Do you know why is it doing that?

Comment: I would guess either your `tyt` list isn't well formed, or you haven't got spaces between your `b` and `E` and / or `c` and `t`.

Comment: Ah the problem was somehow the `(` `)`. I took them out and I got it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help you find your way, it should look something like this:
(I know not posting copyable code goes against the norm but it's simple enough and helps to type it out oneself I believe)

[image]

Comment: Would you also happen to know how to display the fitted parameters and errors on each parameter as a table? I'm also trying to do that.

Comment: Umm... Look up 2 inches? :D

Comment: Oh boy am I blind. Sorry for the troubles and thank you so much again!